# Populating selection box from a text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wanted to populate my selection box from a text file having json data. The Json data is placed in person.txt file. You may also suggest if you have any better way to populate the selection box from external file. I had a large number of selection box to be populated.

```js
var json = {
    "1": "Accountancy",
    "2": "American Studies",
    "3": "Anatomy & Regenerative Biology",
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-inverse" data-width="300px">
  <script type="text/javascript">

 $.getJSON("person.txt", function( json ) {
    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
    $('.selectpicker').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + json[key] + '</option>');
});
});

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine.

Just if you save JSON data, keep your file with **.json** extension and not **.txt**

Comment: It works if i remove the line " $.getJSON("person.txt", function( json ) { " and add the external json file as " <script type="text/javascript" src="person.json"></script> "

Comment: It depends how you save your file. Why it's not working? Which error do you get?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load,  Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 0):

The $.getJSON("person.json", function( json ) {}); treat person.json is on the local server. That means its like "http://localhost/.../person.json". So put that json file on your local machine's IIS. Browse that file form IIS copy that file URL form browser and use like below.
$.getJSON("http://localhost/MyLocalSite/person.json", function( json ) {});

Hope it will help you:)